# error while running libvlcnet(vlc library for .Net)

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to run the libvlcnet solution which is downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/ . 
I tried using "**nant /t:net-2.0 clean build zip**" I got an error "**The SDK for the 'net-2.0' framework is not available or not configured**"(but 2.0 is already installed)  while build stage is in "**generate_asminfo**".

I tried to run the libvlcnet solution from truck folder, "**An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)**" is the error i am getting when i run the solution from visual studio why? I have been breaking my head for 5 hours. Exactly the error is exactly in the constructor of MediaInfoLibrary.

```
    public MediaInfoLibrary() {
        handle = MediaInfoInterop.MediaInfo_New();
    }
```

Am I missing some thing.? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Link about incompatibility of platforms when using external dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-on/2926982#2926982) helped me a bit in figuring out what might be the problem. So i set the target platform to x86 and the dll is blocked by windows by default for preventing malicious activities, generally the problem with external **dll**  or **chm** files. So right click on the dll and unblock the file.

Thank god i finally got it after a day's hard work. :)
If some one get a problem on some thing like this, make a comment over the answer. I will try helping if i can.