# Issue with SSIS deployment package on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

We have an issue with a file system deployment of an SSIS package on tests environnement, DTSINSTALL fails with this error : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) (DTSInstall). This error is displayed juste after a double click on the manifest file

We use the deployment package to setup many config parameters to avoid the end-user to do it manualy on the config file, for this raison we need to make a deployable package and can't do it just by copying manualy the package on the sile system.

This config of the tests environnement is : Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2008 R2 wihout the SSIS Developement Studio but the package was developed on SSIS 2008, is there any incompatibility with the two versions ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing 32-bit and 64-bit? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-o).

Comment: the dev and tests environnements are on a x64 plateforme, we try to build the SSIS Package from a Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2 but the error is the same. we have replaced the tests machine by another machine with the same config but the problem persists, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, the Business Intelligence Development Studio should be installed on production environnement in order to deploy the SSIS package correctly.