# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format, only in relase

Tags: c#, x86, release

I get

> *"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."*

exception when I compile my code in release, in debug all works fine.

Debug and release has the same configuration: main project was compiled in x86, some referenced projects in AnyCPU and my **problem.dll** in x86 too.
I have to compile it in x86 becouse problem.dll use external 32 bit dlls.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p) - [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-o) - [3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110169/Fix-Error-An-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-wi)

Comment: Only in release it doesn't work in debug all work fine...and release and debug have the same configuration, so why in release does'nt work?

Comment: So you changed the Platform target on your EXE file to force it to run in 32-bit mode.  For the Debug configuration.  You'll have to do it again for the Release configuration.  Use Build + Configuration Manager to switch.

Comment: Debug and Release have the same compiler configuration, that's the problem! I don't understand why in release it doesn't works.

Comment: get rid of any of the `Any` - it's 32/64 issue

Comment: If i set all projects in x86 it doesn't work