# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Api application with .NET Framework 4.0 and C# deployed on a Windows 7 Professional 64 bits and IIS 7.0.

When I run the app, http://myHost/WebApi, I get this:

> Can not load file or assembly 'AutomationMiddleware.Common' or one of
>   its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. Description: An unhandled exception when running the
>   current web request. Review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.   Exception Details:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'AutomationMiddleware.Common' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source code error:
>
> Has generated an uncontrolled during the execution of the current web
>   request. Information regarding the origin and location of the
>   exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Trail to load the assembly: The following information can be helpful
>   to determine why no assembly 'AutomationMiddleware.Common' was loaded.
>
> The administrator assemblies are loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable file  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   --- Register of detailed errors.
>
> === Status information prior link === 
>   LOG: DisplayName = AutomationMiddleware.Common
>    (Partial)
>   AVS: partial link information for an assembly is provided:
>   AVS: Assembly Name:. AutomationMiddleware.Common | Domain Id: 2
>   AVS: A partial bond occurs when only provides part of the display name of the assembly.
>   AVS: This may lead to an incorrect load linker assembly.
>   AVS: It is recommended to provide a textual identity completely specified for assembly,
>   AVS: consisting of simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
>   AVS: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this problem.
>   LOG: AppBase = file: /// C: / inetpub / wwwroot / WebAPI /
>   LOG: Initial privatePath = C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ WebAPI \ bin Assembly Call: (Unknown).
>   ===
>   LOG: This link begins in the context of default load.
>   LOG: Using the configuration file of the application: C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ WebAPI \ web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ aspnet.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file in C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \
>   Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ config \ machine.config.
>   LOG: The policy is not being applied to reference at this time (link private assembly, custom, partial, or location-based).
>   
>  LOG: Attempting download of new URL file: /// C: /Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files
>   / WebAPI / d5634960 / b33de11c / AutomationMiddleware.Common.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file: /// C: /Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files / WebAPI / d5634960 / b33de11c / AutomationMiddleware.Common / AutomationMiddleware.Common. DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file: /// C: /inetpub/wwwroot/WebApi/bin/AutomationMiddleware.Common.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete the installation of assembly (hr = 0x8007000B). He ended the search.
>
> Stack trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'AutomationMiddleware.Common' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +210
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +17    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'AutomationMiddleware.Common' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12495956
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +499    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +131    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +331
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +148
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'AutomationMiddleware.Common' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12617668
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12457285
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34237

I have compiled every dll with x86 architecture, and the same error. With anyCPU and the same error. And with x64 and the same error.

`AutomationMiddleware.Common` is an assembly that I have developed. All the assemblies are mine except the nuget ones (Entity Framework, Json.net, etc.).

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add this as a community wiki to help other people to solve this problem.

If you have this problem, please check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926982/68571. Maybe, it could help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like there is very strange bug here:

Did you search the error code you got?

[`Error code 0x80004005`](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/914232)

> This problem may occur if a file that the Windows Product Activation
> (WPA) requires is damaged or missing. This behavior occurs if one or
> both of the following conditions are true:
>
> - A third-party backup utility or an antivirus program interferes with the installation of Windows XP.
> - A file that WPA requires is manually modified.

May be some of the outer dependencies needs to be updated?

Comment: I have tested the same installation in two diferent computers and I get the same error. What do you mean with `May be some of the outer dependencies needs to be updated?`?

Comment: I have solved my problem with this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926982/68571